# Can't create a Team Project for Azure DevOps Server 2019 from Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, tfvc, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-server

I'm trying to create a new Team Project for my Collection on a newly installed Azure DevOps Server 2019 from Visual Studio 2017. I'm able to successfully create the project using the web interface, but when try from VS it fails. Here is the exception entries in the log:

```
---begin Exception entry---
Time: 2019-08-05T10:53:19
Module: Work Item Tracking
Exception Message: VS1640129: The collection you are targeting uses inheritance process model. This operation is not allowed on an inheritance process model based collection. Please refer to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=849010 or contact your system administrator for help. (type VssServiceException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<HandleResponseAsync>d__52.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__50.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__47`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__28`1.MoveNext()

--- end Exception entry ---

2019-08-05T10:53:19 | Module: Work Item Tracking | Thread: 28 | Uploaded WorkItemType definition from C:\Users\natha589\AppData\Local\Temp\TPW_tmpADC0.tmp\WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\Bug.xml.
---begin Exception entry---
Time: 2019-08-05T10:53:19
Module: Engine
Event Description: TF30162: Task "WITs" from Group "WorkItemTracking" failed
Exception Type: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.PcwException
Exception Message: Work item type validation failed. The operation cannot be completed.
Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WitPcwPlugin.PcwPluginComponentCreator.Execute(ProjectCreationContext ctxt, XmlNode taskXml)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.ProjectCreationEngine.TaskExecutor.PerformTask(IProjectComponentCreator componentCreator, ProjectCreationContext context, XmlNode taskXml)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.ProjectCreationEngine.RunTask(Object taskObj)
--   Inner Exception   --
Exception Message: Work item type validation failed. The operation cannot be completed. (type WitPcwFatalException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WitPcwPlugin.PcwPluginComponentCreator.WitPcwTask.WorkItemTypesTask.UploadTypeDefinition(String file, Boolean execute)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WitPcwPlugin.PcwPluginComponentCreator.WitPcwTask.WorkItemTypesTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WitPcwPlugin.PcwPluginComponentCreator.Parse(ContextWrapper wrapper, XmlNode taskXml, Boolean fExecute)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WitPcwPlugin.PcwPluginComponentCreator.Execute(ProjectCreationContext ctxt, XmlNode taskXml)

--- end Exception entry ---
```

My teams are used to creating projects from within Visual Studio, so it would be nice to not have to rely on going to the web UI.

Edit: I'm selecting the Agile process template and TFVC for version control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option has been moved to the web and no longer supported via Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks! Would be nice if that was easily found in the documentation. I guess it might be, but I just couldn't see it.